# Chinese phrase for a physician's "residency program"?

Tags: word-requests, phrase, phrase-request

I am looking for a phrase in Chinese which means the residency program that physicians go through after graduation from medical school. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residency_(medicine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google translates "residency" as "住院醫師" (doctor who live/stay in the hospital ) . I think 駐院醫師 (stationing doctor) is more accurate

*住院 could mean 留醫 (hospitalized; hospitalization)*

> "residency program" for physicians go through after graduation from medical school

The physicians in the program are basically 實習醫師 (intern doctors).

I would translate "residency" as "駐院醫師" and "residency program" as "實習醫師駐院計劃" (intern doctor hospital stationing program)